# When you enter a moderator tag in the body, it isn't formatted

Tags: support, tags, markdown, per-site-meta, moderator-tags

In the tags bar, the moderator only tags have different formatting, as do the required tags:

[image]

But when you use the `[tag:tagname]` markdown, it doesn't format it at all on the per-site meta sites.

Ask Ubuntu:

[image]

Stack Overflow:

[image]

English Language & Usage:

[image]

It does, however format them on this main Meta:

[image]

Is there any reason for this difference?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to prepend `meta-` to the tag keyword, like this:

`[meta-tag:status-completed]` = [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
`[meta-tag:status-declined]` = [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)
`[meta-tag:status-deferred]` = [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)
`[meta-tag:status-bydesign]` = [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

That way, those tags are related to Meta and not counted as main site tags.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that on per-site metas, `[tag:tag-name]` links to that tag on the main site, and `[meta-tag:tag-name]` links to that tag on that meta.